# Spring MVC using maven and eclipse

Tags: spring-mvc

i got stuck with this error.

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Smvc/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

as i run this example

http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

please help anyone....thanks

Comment: please add more details... what steps did you exactly do? I also tried to use this tutorial & found it very incomplete. You can however download the example at the bottom of the page & see it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have renamed the war or configured a different name for the context, the correct URL should be `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome` (and not Smvc/welcome)

Comment: Jasha thanks for ur effort,yes i renamed the war in pom.xml and  i steel getting this error.

Comment: Did you run the example as is, or also rename the package name of the HelloController?
In the Spring configuration you find `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />` which cannot find your controller if you moved it to a different package.